# SQL Update - Deleting last 45 char of a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

I want to delete last 45 char of an attribute in all rows. What can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET fieldname = IF(LENGTH(fieldname) > 45,
                      SUBSTR(fieldname, 1, LENGTH(fieldname) - 45),
                      fieldname)
```

Comment: Isn't SUBSTR 1-based, not zero based?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: fixed too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update table
set column = right(column , 44)
```